# GET Request is driving me to drink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, external

So heres the deal. I've got an html file, with an id="followers". I'm trying to make a get request with jQuery to get the xml tag  from the twitter api:

(http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=nightoutinc

and update the id with the accurate info.

I'm not getting any console errors with my jquery, which leads me to believe everything is hooked up right, I'm just not implementing the get request properly.

My Jquery looks like this:

```
(function ($){

getFollowers = function(){

$.get("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=nightoutinc", function(data){

$("followers").follower_count(data);


});

};

});
```

my html head looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/getfollowers.js">

$(document).ready(function(){

getFollowers();

});

</script>
```

please tell me, what is wrong?!?

-brian

Comment: I think your problem is that your code is in a script element which has a src defined. Move the ready() code to it's own block.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the subject is something meaningful. Also, it helps when you actually explain what's not working like you'd expect and ask a question - posting a bunch of code and saying "please tell me what is wrong?!?" isn't really a question.

Comment: Open up firebug and go to the net tab. Find the request that you are making to the server. Right click and open in a new tab. If there is an XML error the browser will tell you what is wrong. Since you only define a success function you are masking any errors. Also try this request using the .ajax function and define an error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have scope issues. And it doesn't look like your function is being called; only defined. Try wrapping it up into one parent function that actually gets called.

```
(function($) {

    function getFollowers() {
        // Implementation here.
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getFollowers();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery object selecter seems wrong

```
$("followers")
```

Should be

```
$("#followers")
```

Notice the pound sign which indicates ID

Answer (score 0):

You said the response was XML right? Then `data` is going to be an XML DOM not a string or HTML you can jsut insert into your page.

I can only find the docs for JSON but assuming the XML has parity:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=nightoutinc', function(xml){
        nbFollowers = $(xml).find('followers_count').text();
        $('#followers').html(nbFollowers ? nbFollowers : 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you define follower_count?

I guess  it should be $("followers").html(data); NOT $("followers").follower_count(data);